# Json error calling MarshalJSON for type json.RawMessage

Tags: json, go, marshalling

I am getting following error while trying to marshal this struct

> json: error calling MarshalJSON for type json.RawMessage: unexpected
>   end of JSON input

for the object of below struct

```
type Chart struct {
    ID          int             `json:"id,omitempty" db:"id"`
    Name        string          `json:"name,omitempty" db:"name"`
    Type        string          `json:"type,omitempty" db:"type"`
    DashboardID int             `json:"dashboard_id,omitempty"`
    SourceType  string          `json:"source_type,omitempty" db:"source_type"`
    Data        json.RawMessage `json:"graph_data,ommitempty"`
}

func main() {
    chart := Chart{}
    chart.ID = 1
    chart.Name = "Jishnu"
    str, err := json.Marshal(chart)
    fmt.Println(err)
}
```

Comment: The json is valid?

Comment: @Flimzy added code for reproducing the error

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Fixed by making `Chart.Data` a pointer

```
 Data        *json.RawMessage `json:"data,omitempty"`
```

Go 1.8 (currently rc3 as of writing) will correctly handle Marshalling of both pointer type and non-pointer types of json.RawMessage.

Fixing commit:
https://github.com/golang/go/commit/1625da24106b610f89ff7a67a11581df95f8e234

Comment: I know this is old but I'm dealing with the same issue so it might be worth pointing out the typo in "ommitempty". All the others have the correct value "omitempty".